# Vuejs / NuxtJs include components from dynamically set directory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJs / VueJs

I have a problem where by i need to set the path of a component dynamically. Why I hear you ask ?

Well I am creating a set of sites that will use the same basic codebase but only the look and feel will differ and thus for each domain want to load the components from the specific dir. The basic component names etc will remain the same just want to be able to change a few things which are beyond just some v-if statements in the component or css.

eg. 
 Site1: sites/mysite/HomePageHero.vue
 Site2: sites/yoursite/HomePageHero.vue

Now i know about dynamic components but the problem there is i will have to add each sites components to the page every time i create a new site and i dont want to do that. So the more sites I create the bigger that list will get.

I just want to set the site name in the .env add the components to the dir and it all works (or something similar)

So if you take my code below , i need the DYNAMICHERE to be dynamic. There is probably something simple that I am missing.

`import HomePageHero from '@/components/sites/DYNAMICHERE/HomePageHero'`

Just for clarification as per the first response to this . I have tried doing the following which doesn't obviously work

`import HomePageHero from '@/components/sites/' + process.env.THEME . + '/HomePageHero'`

Answer (score 1):

I finally got some time to play around with this and I fixed the problem which was best for my solution using the following code

I am using dotenv to define the env variables

`const HomePageHero = () => import('@/components/sites/' + process.env.WEBSITE_NAME + '/HomePageHero');`

Hattip to this article:

https://vuedose.tips/tips/dynamic-imports-in-vue-js-for-better-performance/

There still may be a cleaner solution but this works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel then you have 1 option: `process.env.YOUR_SITE`

Answer (score 0):

This is what we're doing:

1. declare site names in package.json
2. use same name for mongodb
3. import components and use the one that matches mongodb process.env name

```
  "scripts": {
    "siteOne": "cross-env MONGO_DB=siteOne API_URL=http://localhost:3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "siteTwo": "cross-env MONGO_DB=siteTwo API_URL=http://localhost:3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build_siteOne": "MONGO_DB=siteOne nuxt build",
    "build_siteTwo": "MONGO_DB=siteTwo nuxt build",
    "start": "node server/index.js",
  },
```

```
<template>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <component :is="footerComponent"></component>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import Footer_siteOne from '~/components/Footer_siteOne.vue';
  import Footer_siteTwo from '~/components/Footer_siteTwo.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      Footer_siteOne,
      Footer_siteTwo,
    },
    computed: {
      footerComponent: function() {
        return 'Footer_'+process.env.MONGO_DB;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah i thought of that solution too , but using dotenv and not package json. However i dont want to have to list 

 import Footer_siteOne from '~/components/Footer_siteOne.vue';
  import Footer_siteTwo from '~/components/Footer_siteTwo.vue';

etc everytime i had a site (if possible , if not then i have no choice)